# Mitmproxy reverse proxy listen_port not taking

Tags: reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

I’ve set up a simple mitm reverse proxy on Ubuntu:

```
mitmproxy --mode reverse:http://host.example.com/ --set \
block_global=false --set listen_port=80
```

The `listen_port` is being ignored; I get RSTs back for requests sent on 80 (8080 is still in play). What I really want the reverse proxy to listen on both 80 and 443.

Separately, but related, I'm struggling to find up-to-date and accurate documentation - https://mitmproxy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.2/ is not the answer -; what are people using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding documentation - on project's website there's Docs -> v4 (latest release).

Comment: I'd been through all of them, read them again, and tried mitmdump rather then mitmproxy and seem to be getting somewhere. 

The graphic for "Modes of Operation: Reverse Proxy" has mitmproxy everywhere, I'd assumed that the one occurrence of mitmdump in the text was a typo...

Comment: does not work for me .v 8